# I can't convert the json date

Tags: python

I have a small code in python that what I try to do is show me the date but I can't get it to show me, the date is generated by a url in json:
this is the url:.
https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web-news/es/production/front.json

and what I try is to be published with this code:

`import time

```
time.ctime(int("1667300455000"))

print(time.strftime("%D %H:%M", time.localtime(int("1667300455000"))))`
```

```
throws me the error:
```

```
time.ctime(int("1667300455000"))
    OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

```
but it doesn't show me
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I don't know why
https://i.imgur.com/R7DRYC5.png

Comment: @raulinho check out my answer, I think I found your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that `1667300455000` is simply too far in the future.

I suspect that your JSON gives the time in milliseconds and therefore, we need to divide it by `1000`.

```
time.ctime(int("1667300455"))
'Tue Nov  1 12:00:55 2022'
```

Now this date looks correct ^^